# How using train OpenCV CvNormalBayesClassifier?

Tags: c++, opencv, classification

**GOAL:**

I want to use CvNormalBayesClassifier to determine whether the text in image is hand-written or not.

**WHAT HAVE BEEN TRIED:**

I detect keypoints of my image JPG (input).

```cpp
SiftFeatureDetector detector;
vector<KeyPoint> keypoints;
detector.detect(input, keypoints);
```

And I compute descriptors.

```cpp
Mat descript;
SiftDescriptorExtractor deExtrac;
deExtrac.compute(input, keypoints, descript);
```

I have problem understanding how to use the function

```cpp
bool CvNormalBayesClassifier::train(const Mat& trainData, const Mat& responses, const Mat& varIdx=Mat(), const Mat& sampleIdx=Mat(), bool update=false );
```

I tried this:

```cpp
Mat trainingClassifications(100, 1, CV_32FC1); 
CvNormalBayesClassifier *bayes = new CvNormalBayesClassifier;

bayes->train(descript, trainingClassifications);
bayes->save("bayes.model");
```

**PROBLEM:**

I got the following error:

```cpp
OpenCV Error: Sizes of input arguments do not match (Response array must contain as many elements as the total number of samples) in cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses, 
file /Users/.../opencv/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp, line 671
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type cv::Exception: /Users/.../opencv/modules/ml/src/inner_functions.cpp:671: 
error: (-209) Response array must contain as many elements as the total number of samples in function cvPreprocessCategoricalResponses
```

Comment: "Response array must contain as many elements as the total number of samples" - if your response has 100 rows, your descript Mat needs 100 rows, too. and there's the problem: your SiftFeatureDetector will return a *varying* number of descriptor rows, you will either need some procrustes or filtering solution, or apply BOW, so you get a fixed size for each image.

Comment: Could you explain it more clearly? I have no idea why SiftFeatureDetector generates an array of 128 columns. I want 1 columns?